# EF 5.0 inserting null into smallint column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.5

I have a column with SQL type of smallint (EF type of Int16) that I want to insert a null value into but when I use the below code I get the error that null can not be converted to short. How can I get this one line if statment to allow me to insert a null?

```
CollectionID = (ddlCollection.SelectedValue == "None") ? null  : Convert.ToInt16(ddlCollection.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: The title does not describe the issue in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working code is to do a nullablecnvert like:

```
CollectionID = (ddlCollection.SelectedValue == "None") ? (Nullable<Int16>)null : Convert.ToInt16(ddlCollection.SelectedValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

c# has a values for null in database:
    DBNull.Value

Comment: @user1365911 Then your title is not the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that your Entity Framework property `CollectionID` must be marked as Nullable (if you're using EDMX) or declared as `short?` or `Nullable<short>` if you're using Code First.

Secondly, you need to make sure the database type for that column is also marked as nullable (something like `smallint NULL` in SQL Server).

**EDIT:** Ah, I think I see the problem now. Try casting your call to `Convert.ToInt16` to `Nullable<short>`. The ternary operator sees a `null` on the `true` side, and type incompatible with the `null` value on the `false` side, which is causing your error.

```
CollectionID = (ddlCollection.SelectedValue == "None")
    ? (Nullable<short>)null 
    : (Nullable<short>)Convert.ToInt16(ddlCollection.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: Everthing is setup as nullable in EF and SQL. The problem is happening way before I even hit the DB. I can not build since VS2012 is throwing the error listed in first post.

Comment: Your edit is equivalant to my current code, the error is thrown on the null varable not the ddlCollection. The goal is that if None is selected in the drop down to insert null otherwise insert the selectedvalue.

Comment: I edited my answer once more. The first branch of the conditional operator is what dictates the return type of the expression, so the `null` must be casted to `Nullable<short>` for the whole thing to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use it with sqlcommand parameter

```
 if(ddl_collection.selectedvalue!="None")
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CollectionID", Convert.ToInt16(ddlcollection.selectedValue));
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CollectionID", DBNull.Value);
```